# Measuring the area of the object using camera and known distance between the camera and the object

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Is it possible to get the real area of an object focused by the camera if we know the distance of the camera from the object?
For example consider we are taking a photo of a wall from a known distance. Is it possible to find the area of the wall captured by the camera.
This is for an Android app so is there anything from the API that can help me.
i got a formula where we have to use the sensor height but as i researched into it its not possible to find the camera sensor size of all the phones.

Any inputs are welcome. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually worked a way around this.
Firstly I used getVerticalViewAngle() and getHorizontalViewAngle() methods of the Camera.Parameters class. I used it in the formula given below:

tan(θ/2) = x/2z
where θ is the angle i get from the above methods and x is the height/width(depending on which of the 2 methods I am using) of the object and z is the distance of the object from the camera.

The result is quite accurate provided you have measured the distance correctly and also the angle at which you have hold your camera(It must be parallel ideally as @type-alpha suggested).

```
Camera.Parameters cp = camera.getParameters();
    double distance = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
    /*double height = distance * 2.57/cp.getFocalLength();
    double width = distance * 3.42/cp.getFocalLength();*/
    double realheight = 2 * distance * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(cp.getVerticalViewAngle() / 2));
    double realwidth = 2 * distance * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(cp.getHorizontalViewAngle() / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done but:

a) the plane containing your phone and the plane containing your object needs to be parallel, that is, the line coming out of your camera must be normal to the surface to measure;

b) you need one additional calibration step (a one time only setup done at first launch of the application), e.g. knowing how an object x meters long at a distance of y meters appear on your screen (x and y must be known). For example knowing how many pixels are needed on your image for an object 1 meter long at a distance of 1 meter. Note that the calibration process must respect a).

At this point it should be a matter of basic geometry since the area goes like the square of the distance and the lenght is directly proportional to the distance.

Example:

- calibration: object 1 meter away and 1 meter long takes 10 pixels. So you know that at 1 meter, 100 pixels on your screen forming a connected surface, corresponds roughly to 1 meter squared.
- problem instance: object 3 meter away takes 150 pixels of the screen.
- solution: at 2 meters, 100 pixels are 4 m^2. at 3 meters, 100 pixels are 9 m^2. Then at 3 meters your 150 pixels corresponds to 13.5 m^2.

Note that in the calibration process you can use an area instead of a length but the idea is the same.

NOTE also that this only works if the camera can be considered the origin of the projection which I'm not quite sure. If it is not the origin of the projection than you need to know the distance w between the camera/phone plane and the ideal projection origin (which should be costant). At this point you use the same process as before, keeping in mind that to every distance you got to add w before doing any calculation.

Note 3 (and then I stop): you can do the calibration in other ways such as knowing the pixels occupied by the same object at two different distances.

Comment: hey I have worked a way around this. You can refer to my answer below.Thanks for your help.