# Measure Distance Between Camera And Object in front of camera

Tags: android, camera

As this question has been asked already, i didnt get any clear idea in it. So i am asking this question again.I am struggling with it for two days.
         I want to calculate the distance between camera of my devices with that of the object that are infront of camera.
         I tried to use sensor managers as it was suggested in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949777/how-can-we-measure-distance-between-object-and-android-phone-camera) but i am getting wrong results in it.

I have used two sensors **accelerometer** and **magnetic field**.

I calculate the distance based on orientation of the device as suggested in the above link.

onSensorChanged Callback in Sensor listener

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            gravity = event.values.clone();

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            geoMagnetic = event.values.clone();

        if (gravity != null && geoMagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity,
                    geoMagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                azimuth = 57.29578F * orientation[0];
                pitch = 57.29578F * orientation[1];
                roll = 57.29578F * orientation[2];

            }
        }


    }
```

Portrait:

```
double dist = Math.abs((float) (1.4f * Math.tan(roll * Math.PI / 180)));
```

Landscape:

```
double dist = Math.abs((float) (1.4f * Math.tan(pitch* Math.PI / 180)));
```

Please provide information about how to calculate the distance. Any ideas and suggestion are appreciable,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738177/measuring-the-area-of-the-object-using-camera-and-known-distance-between-the-cam hope it will help u!!

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay Thanks for your reply. Actually I need to calculate the distance between object and camera. I dont need to find the width and height of the object.